# Git shows .pdf file is changed in working directory in Macbook after cloning from GitHub. How to resolve this issue?

Tags: git, macos, github, version-control

After cloning the repo from GitHub, my `git status` command showing as .pdf file is changed in my current working directory. I am using MacBook Air 2017 version.

I tried

`checkout`,

`reset`,

`delete`,

`config.filemode.`

`config.autocrlf`

Nothing is working for me. Even `git stash` is not working to stash pdf file.

People whoever pushing files to this repo using Linux Mint operating system. I am the only one first time cloned this repo on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s mainly caused by the different line endings between mac and linux OS.

You can try with below commands:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
touch .gitattributes
echo '* text=auto' >>  .gitattributes
git add . -u
rm .git/index
git reset
git add -u
git add .gitattributes
git commit
```

**Note:** before run above commands, you shouldn’t commit any changes after cloning.

More details, you can refer [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/).